# Connection between docker containers as localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i am trying to dockerize my web application. i am running a apache webserver + mariadb and redis server as you can see in my docker-compose file combined with an nginx proxy to use local domains and ssl.

everything works fine as long is i use the container names to connect to mysql / redis. I dont want to change all localhosts in my code to the mysql / redis container names.

Is there a way to keep "localhost" as Host instead of the containers name?

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: portal-proxy
    networks:
      - portal
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
  portal:
    image: portal:latest
    container_name: portal-webserver
    networks:
      - portal
    volumes:
      - ./portal:/var/www/html/portal
    links:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: portal.dev
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: portal-db
    networks:
      - portal
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: portal
      MYSQL_USER: www-data
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: www-data
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdf1234
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: portal-redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - portal
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
networks:
  portal:
    name: portal
```

Comment: Add `127.0.0.1` in your port mapping => `- "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"`

Comment: @AppyGG i dont think `127.0.0.1` in port mappings will work, since it is a loopback interface. Have you ever tried that mapping?

Comment: If you hard-coded `localhost` in your application code, you'll basically never be able to deploy it in any environment other than your development system.  (Also consider running this on AWS, where you can get hosted Redis and MySQL databases, which also won't be `localhost`.)  You should make this configurable in your code.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Yea my bad, didn't understand that localhost was hardcoded in the other container code

Answer (score 0):

Use a common hostname (`staging.docker.host`) on all containers, that resolves to the docker host's ip `1.2.3.4`.

So adding this to containers:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "staging.docker.host:1.2.3.4"
```

and use that name (`staging.docker.host`) in all you connection endpoints.

On you local machine you also add (`staging.docker.host`) to your `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with localhost `127.0.0.1 staging.docker.host`.